# javascript problem with implicitly typed variables

Tags: javascript, variables, typed

Forgive this novice question (novice in Javascript!).

In a html page I have a set of images with a name and a number: img1 img2 img3... img12...
And there is a JS function where I need to iterate from (say) **img5** to last img.

If I write this:

```
function iterateImg(objImgID) {var imgNum = objImgID.replace("img","");
    for (i=imgNum+1;i<20;i++)
    .../...
```

The variable "i" is treated as a string, and i+1 receive the value "51" if the passed object's ID is img5.

Of course I can still iterate from 1 to n and only perform the desired task when the value of i reaches 6, but that would be an ugly fix.

How can I fix this please? How can I create a variable that will be treated as an integer before I use it as seed?
Besides, what would you recommend as best practice?

Comment: Don't forget to declare 'i' with var. If you don't, 'i' may get attached to the global scope (window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var imgNum = Number(objImgID.replace("img",""));
```

That'll do it.

Or better yet (because I love regex)

```
var imgNum = Number(objImgID.match(/[0-9]+/));
```

Comment: Guys, I have to tank you all! 4 answers in less than 10 minutes, that's great!

Comment: Is there a functional difference between using `Number` and `parseInt` or is it just a matter of style?

Comment: For those interested. It looks like there is at least a minor functional difference.  For example `Number(true) === 1` and `parseInt(true)` results in NaN

Answer (score 1):

Use `parseInt` to convert the string to a number

```
var imgNum = parseInt(objImgID.replace("img", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to force JavaScript to convert it into a number

- `parseInt(x, 10)` - the 10 is the base of the number
- `x - 0` - subtracting only works for numbers
- `x * 1` - multiplying also

Answer (score 0):

```
var imgNum = parseInt(objImgID.replace("img",""), 10);
```

Now when you do `var i=imgNum+1`, it will perform addition of 2 integers.

Comment: ok so why are you guys using `parseInt()` instead of `Number()`? I'm going to assume there's some kind of speed aspect or something?

Comment: @Joseph, performance would be pretty equivalent but if you are interested in concrete numbers take a look here: http://jsperf.com/number-vs-parseint-vs-plus/3